# Tag based Push notification example in IBM worklight

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Question 1:
I am trying to implement Tag based push notification with IBM worklight. As suggested in training material i have added Tags in application-descriptor file. Also I have subscribed for that particular tagname in `main.js` file.

Steps followed:

1. Added Tags in application-descriptor.xml with tag Name OFFERS.
2. Subscribed for that Tag with `WL.Client.PushsubscribeTag("OFFERS",    {onSuccess:doSubscribeSuccess , onFailure: doSubscribeFailure})` in `WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe` function.
3. Have added `WL.client.Push.onMessage(props,payload)` to handle recieved notifications.
4. On loading application it goes to `doSubscribeMethod` in `main.js`(attached) but doesn't invoke callback method doSubscribeSuccess.
5. While invoking adapter to send notification(SubmitBroadcastNotification procedure) I have mentioned tagname(OFFERS) to which i had subscribed.
6. In console it shows `Failed to send Notification Reason FPWSE0009E. No devices found`

Question2:
The WL.Server.CreateEventsource when will be this procedure invoked.

Note: All steps about Push notifications configurations are followed and Sample code provided for event based push is working fine.

**EDIT:**
I have attached below logcat for error higlighted in log snippet below.

07-18 18:19:19.253: D/CordovaLog(1081): file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js: Line 1061 : processMessage failed: Stack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideView' of undefined
07-18 18:19:19.253: D/CordovaLog(1081):     at wlEnvInit (file:///android_asset/www/default/js/main.js:77:78)
07-18 18:19:19.253: D/CordovaLog(1081):     at file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7638:5
07-18 18:19:19.253: D/CordovaLog(1081):     at Object.onSuccess (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7665:5)
07-18 18:19:19.253: D/CordovaLog(1081):     at finalizeInit (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:6972:15)
07-18 18:19:19.253: D/CordovaLog(1081):     at Object. (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7812:7)
07-18 18:19:19.253: D/CordovaLog(1081):     at Object. (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1202:33)
07-18 18:19:19.253: D/CordovaLog(1081):     at file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1047:30
07-18 18:19:19.253: D/CordovaLog(1081):     at Object.resolveWith (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1158:7)
07-18 18:19:19.253: D/CordovaLog(1081):     at Object.resolve (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1247:34)
07-18 18:19:19.253: D/CordovaLog(1081):     at deviceIDSuccessCallback (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7732:22)
07-18 18:19:19.253: I/Web Console(1081): processMessage failed: Stack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideView' of undefined
07-18 18:19:19.253: I/Web Console(1081):     at wlEnvInit (file:///android_asset/www/default/js/main.js:77:78)
07-18 18:19:19.253: I/Web Console(1081):     at file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7638:5
07-18 18:19:19.253: I/Web Console(1081):     at Object.onSuccess (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7665:5)
07-18 18:19:19.253: I/Web Console(1081):     at finalizeInit (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:6972:15)
07-18 18:19:19.253: I/Web Console(1081):     at Object. (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7812:7)
07-18 18:19:19.253: I/Web Console(1081):     at Object. (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1202:33)
07-18 18:19:19.253: I/Web Console(1081):     at file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1047:30
07-18 18:19:19.253: I/Web Console(1081):     at Object.resolveWith (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1158:7)
07-18 18:19:19.253: I/Web Console(1081):     at Object.resolve (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1247:34)
07-18 18:19:19.253: I/Web Console(1081):     at deviceIDSuccessCallback (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7732:22) at file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js:1061
07-18 18:19:19.263: D/CordovaLog(1081): file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js: Line 1062 : processMessage failed: Message: S01 DeviceAuth365622402 s90e2f8ab-3e50-3564-921f-b4887579e4a2
07-18 18:19:19.263: I/Web Console(1081): processMessage failed: Message: S01 DeviceAuth365622402 s90e2f8ab-3e50-3564-921f-b4887579e4a2 at file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js:1062
07-18 18:19:19.313: E/NONE(1081): Connectivity to MBaaS established successfully
07-18 18:19:19.323: W/PluginManager(1081): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to LoggerPlugin.log blocked the main thread for 22ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
07-18 18:19:19.383: D/NONE(1081): Ganesh doSubscribe featurefalse
07-18 18:19:19.443: W/PluginManager(1081): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to LoggerPlugin.log blocked the main thread for 19ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
07-18 18:19:19.453: D/NONE(1081): Ganesh doSubscribe feature entered
07-18 18:19:19.484: W/PluginManager(1081): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to LoggerPlugin.log blocked the main thread for 40ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
07-18 18:19:19.543: E/NONE(1081): **Can't subscribe, notification token is not updated on the server**
07-18 18:19:19.563: D/dalvikvm(1081): GC_CONCURRENT freed 426K, 26% free 3050K/4080K, paused 14ms+35ms, total 195ms

Comment: Can you try to format your question a little better? It's a bit hard to follow as is. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application was based on the Tag notifications sample, it would not have used `WL.Server.createEventSource`, as that API method is used for Event Source-based notifications and not Tag-based notifications.

Make sure you are following the correct sample for Tag-based notifications, which can be found here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/tag-based-notifications/

Next, it is not clear if you are testing on iOS or Android, and whether or not you have set it up correctly. Be sure that you have: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/

Now, you need to make sure to follow the implementation step of the sample application ([download link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/docs/v700/TagBasedPushNotificationsProject.zip)). Look at this main.js implementation snippet from the sample:

```
//---------------------------- Check if push support is available ----------------------
function isPushSupported() {
    var isSupported = false;
    if (WL.Client.Push){
        isSupported = WL.Client.Push.isPushSupported();
    }   
    WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", JSON.stringify(isSupported), [ {
        text : 'Close',
        handler : function() {}
      }
      ]);
}

//---------------------------- Set up push notifications -------------------------------
if (WL.Client.Push) {   
    WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function() {
        WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", "Ready to subscribe", [ {
            text : 'Close',
            handler : function() {}
          }
          ]);

        $('.subscribeToTagButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.unsubscribeFromTagButton').removeAttr('disabled');
    };
}

// --------------------------------- Subscribe to tag ----------------------------------
function subscribeToSampleTag1() {
    WL.Client.Push.subscribeTag("sample-tag1", {
        onSuccess: subscribeTagSuccess,
        onFailure: subscribeTagFailure
    });
}

function subscribeToSampleTag2() {
    WL.Client.Push.subscribeTag("sample-tag2", {
        onSuccess: subscribeTagSuccess,
        onFailure: subscribeTagFailure
    });
}

function subscribeTagSuccess() {
    WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", "Subscribed to tag", [ {
        text : 'Close',
        handler : function() {}
      }
      ]);
}

function subscribeTagFailure() {
    WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", "Failed subscribing to tag", [ {
        text : 'Close',
        handler : function() {}
      }
      ]);
}

// ------------------------------- Check if subscribed ---------------------------------
function isSubscribedToTags() {
    var subscribedTagsSample1 = WL.Client.Push.isTagSubscribed("sample-tag1");
    var subscribedTagsSample2 = WL.Client.Push.isTagSubscribed("sample-tag2");

    WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", 'sample-tag1: ' + subscribedTagsSample1 + '\n' + 'sample-tag2: ' + subscribedTagsSample2, [ {
        text : 'Close',
        handler : function() {}
      }
      ]);
}

// ------------------------------- Unsubscribe from tag --------------------------------
function unsubscribeFromSampleTag1() {
    WL.Client.Push.unsubscribeTag("sample-tag1", {
        onSuccess: unsubscribeTagSuccess,
        onFailure: unsubscribeTagFailure
    });
}

function unsubscribeFromSampleTag2() {
    WL.Client.Push.unsubscribeTag("sample-tag2", {
        onSuccess: unsubscribeTagSuccess,
        onFailure: unsubscribeTagFailure
    });
}

function unsubscribeTagSuccess(response) {
    WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", "Unsubscribe from tag", [ {
        text : 'Close',
        handler : function() {}
      }
      ]);
}

function unsubscribeTagFailure(response) {
    WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", "Failed subscribing from tag", [ {
        text : 'Close',
        handler : function() {}
      }
      ]);
}

//------------------------------- Handle received notification ---------------------------------------
WL.Client.Push.onMessage = function (props, payload) {
    WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", "Provider notification data: " + JSON.stringify(props), [ {
        text : 'Close',
        handler : function() {
            WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", "Application notification data: " + JSON.stringify(payload), [ {
                text : 'Close',
                handler : function() {}
              }]);      
        }
    }]);
};
```

Comment: Hi Idan  Thanks for the reply. My app would be using both event based and Tag based notification. As of now i am using android for testing this. I will try with sample program as suggested by you. Could you kindly let me know abt invocation of WL.Server.createEventSource. As in when and where will be this called. Also suggest if i am using both type of notifications should i keep event source code in seperate js file??

Comment: Code separation is applicative... write it how it is more convenient for you. You can use event source notifications only after you are logged in. Review the event source notification tutorial.

Comment: now the tag based notification tutorial is working fine. But the same while trying to integrate with my app i am getting ** Can't subscribe notification server is not updated on server ** . Is it mandatory to call `WL.Client.connect` before calling subscribe.

Comment: Have updated my original question. Kindly suggest on the error i have posted

Comment: Yes, attempt to connect first.